# Show information over image on rollover

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover, rollover

I want to be able to show information (HTML basically) over an image when the mouse rolls over the image... I know there is a `.hover()` jQuery function but am unsure how to use it to get the desired effect.

Ideally when a user hovers over an image it would "grey out" (e.g. layer of 50% opacity black) with some HTML like a title etc etc.

Can someone point me in the right direction or provide sample code

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

Wrap your image and the div to display, like this:

```
<div class="imgHover">
    <div class="hover">Test Content for the hover</div>
    <img src="myImage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

With CSS like this:

```
.imgHover .hover { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

And finally, the jQuery using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) like this:

```
$(".imgHover").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.25)
           .end().children(".hover").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1)
           .end().children(".hover").hide();
});
```

[You can try the above code out here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCJwy/)

This fades the image out and displays the `<div>` above it when you hover, the wrapping is so that the `<div>` is absolutely positioned directly above the `<img>`, if you need a lot of wrapping content, give your `.hover` div the same dimensions as the image...just depends on the exact look you're going for.

Comment: Nice answer Nick! And jsfiddle is awesome!

Comment: I haven't tried implementing this but on first look it looks superb!!

Comment: How do I get the image to have a 50% (or whatever) black mask over the top, instead of it fading out?

Comment: @Chris - You can give the wrapping div a black background, same effect :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery anyway, you might want a Tooltips plugin:
http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/